# Why is alternating query filter order is not giving me the same results

Tags: sql, oracle

I m working on some jasper report, I m trying to make an upgrade based on client requirements
however I did found this simple filter that is not giving the same results `('N' = 'Y' OR 'N' = 'N' AND prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100)` vs `('Y' = 'Y' OR 'Y' = 'N' AND prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100)`

The last filter is ignoring the `(prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100)` and giving me more results.

How is really sql processing this line

Thanks

Comment: The documentation has [a section about condition precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the operator AND has higher precedence than the operator OR.
 
Your 1st condition:

```
'N' = 'Y' OR 'N' = 'N' AND prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100
```

is equivalent to:

```
false or (true and prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100)
```

equivalent to:

```
false or prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100
```

equivalent to:

```
prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100
```

So this 1st condition returns all the rows where `prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100`.

And the 2nd condition:

```
'Y' = 'Y' OR 'Y' = 'N' AND prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100
```

is equivalent to:

```
true or (false and prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100)
```

equivalent to:

```
true or false
```

equivalent to:

```
true
```

So this 2nd condition evaluates to `true` and returns all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

1) `'Y'` is never equal to `'N'` so remove that (and the other useless clause) and look at what you're left with

2) Always, always, always use brackets when mixing AND and OR so that your intent is clear to the DB (and fellow developers) on how to group logical truths

```
Name = 'Lee' AND Age = 30 OR Gender = 'Male'
```

Is that

```
--only 30 year olds called Lee, or anyone who is male
(Name = 'Lee' AND Age = 30) OR Gender = 'Male'
```

Or is it

```
--only people called Lee who are 30 or Male
Name = 'Lee' AND (Age = 30 OR Gender = 'Male')
```

Sure, there are rules of precedence for operators, and you can know them (the phrasing of the question indicates you might not know them) and work out what the DB is doing, but it's far more descriptive to another human who has to read and maintain your code, to just use brackets to clearly express your intent.

If you follow the rule of "use brackets when mixing AND and OR" then you won't need to remember whether AND is more important than OR

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has precedence over `OR`, so in your second query the last part (`prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100`) is not being evaluated because 'Y' = 'N' will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`.

Which means `('Y' = 'Y' OR 'Y' = 'N' AND prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100)` is equal to:

`('Y' = 'Y' OR ('Y' = 'N' AND prod.XX_SalesContext_ID<>1000100))` which since `'Y' = 'Y'` is `true` just shows all records.

Lastly I can give better advice if you show more of your code. What you show is some edited version, yes?